# TextField remove last letter while saving to cache

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to save a string in cache from TextField but everytime I save a text it just doesn't save the last letter here is my code.

```
val value = sharedPref.getString("api", "Invalid")
val context = LocalContext.current
var apiState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val pushString = sharedPref.edit().putString("api", apiState).apply()
```

And `onclick` I'm executing that pushString

Comment: Then this is not the code you should be sharing. It should be all the occurrences of `apiState` because that is what is being modified. Anyway, it's pointless to think that `remember` is chopping off the last letter off your string, the error is clearly in the implementation. Also, in hindsight, it could be that your `Text` is too small to fit the value. Did you actually try to debug the code and evaluate the value? You can press Alt when it hits a breakpoint. Just hover your mouse over the variable and press Alt. This assumes you are using Android Studio.

Comment: @MARSK thanks for your effort but I have fixed it see the Question I have added the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I don't know where the bug was but fixed with the code below

```
val sharedPref = this@MainActivity.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
val getString = sharedPref.getString("api", "Invalid")
val apiState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
         value = apiState.value,
         onValueChange = { apiState.value = it },
)
Button(onClick = { sharedPref.edit().putString("api",apiState.value).apply() }) {
    Text(text = "Cache")
}
```